# ASP.NET MVC Page - Dropdown control doesn't function with Keyboard Arrow Keys

Tags: jquery

I have a page that has a Dropdown control (**ddlDeliveryMethod**). So that when the user selects particular option from the Dropdown(**using MOUSE**), the respective Div ID's are loaded.

But instead of Mouse, if we simply use the **arrow keys from Keyboard**, the respective DIV ID's are not showing.

Is there any workaround for this. Appreciate your responses.

Here is my code:

```
// based on Delivery method, display the respective fields
        $("#ddlDeliveryMethod").change(function() {
            $('#divRegisteredMail').hide();
            $('#divRegisteredEmail').hide();
            $('#divRegisteredFax').hide();
            $('#divSaveForFuture').hide();
            switch ($("#ddlDeliveryMethod ").val()) {
                case ' -- Select one -- ':
                    break;
                case 'Email':
                    $('#divRegisteredEmail').show();
                    break;
                case 'Mail':
                    $('#divRegisteredMail').show();
                    break;
                case 'Fax':
                    $('#divRegisteredFax').show();
                    break;
                default:
                    caption = "default";
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is technically more a jQuery question than an ASP.NET question. I've slightly modified your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the keydown event as well as the change...

```
$("#ddlDeliveryMethod").keydown(function() {
 ...
});
```

Comment: @Rita - Please accept that answer if this solved your problem.